# c# API or SDK for st-link v2 or SEGGER J-Link flash downloader

Tags: c#, user-interface, microcontroller, stm32

I am wondering if anyone have worked with a custom .net C# GUI that are able to do flash download for an STM microcontroller via [ST-Link](https://www.arduino-tech.com/st-link-v2-st-link-v2cn-stlink-debugger-emulator-downloader-manager-stm8-stm32/) or [SEGGER](https://www.segger.com/products/production/flasher-st/models/flasher-stm8/)? I know that segger have their [SDK](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/technology/j-link-sdk/), but it is not free. Are there any opensource API that we can use instead?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to program flash images to a microcontroller? Why not simply call `JLink.exe` via command line from your application? You could also use OpenOCD for STLink, and perhaps for JLink - since it is open source, you can integrate it any way you want.

Comment: Ah, just know about it. Thanks for your answer, @Erlkoenig !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to program uCs from your C application just use openOCD (free) and send commands to it. Works with almost every popular debug probe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @P__J__ ! Just knew about this and will try to integrate it!